# Prevent sentence from breaking line after p tag

Tags: html, css

Here is the code, is there a way to prevent "sending" word from breaking line ? I cannot change the p tag to span because the animation won't work.

```css
.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid blue;
  border-right: 16px solid green;
  border-bottom: 16px solid red;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="loader"></p> <span style="white-space:nowrap;"> Sending . . . </span>
```

Comment: It's `white-space:nowrap` (not `no-wrap`)

Comment: thanks kukkuz for your help. Here is the code, play with it :  http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FB7OGYQP0U3R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create a *wrapper* for the `p` and the `span` and make it a *flexbox* - see demo below:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
}
.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid blue;
  border-right: 16px solid green;
  border-bottom: 16px solid red;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="loader"></p> <span> Sending . . . </span>
</div>
```

Comment: And another option is to create 100 wrappers and alternate display `table`, `flex`,  `block` and `inline-block` at different levels. Why would you wrap something in a `flexbox` container if all you want is for it not to wrap?

Comment: there are so many html properties out there.. i had no idea about flex, that was the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.loader{
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think u wont to doing like this

*here css code*

```
span {
  left: 29px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. Content is not displayed properly, you can post the full code of your work in the code editor to see what you are doing